# FieldError at /answer/ Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choices are: add_time, answer, detail, id,

Tags: python, django

believe it or not I've been here for 4 hours trying to get this to work, so yes, I've been trying to make a question and answer site, currently trying to make an answer form so I can send in answers to the question that I am currently viewing, trying to get the id of the question so I can attach the answer into that, but I'm getting this error, I'm sure I wrote 'id' but it thinks I wrote 'i'... What? Anyway here is the traceback, please tell me what I am doing wrong, thanks.

Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/answer/

Django Version: 4.0.4
Python Version: 3.8.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.humanize',
 'forum',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'users',
 'vote']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 84, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 119, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 184, in post
    return super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py", line 153, in post
    return self.form_valid(form)
  File "/home/titsnium/Documents/eduzec/forum/views.py", line 78, in form_valid
    form.question = Question.objects.get('id')
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 482, in get
    clone = self._chain() if self.query.combinator else self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1071, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1089, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone._filter_or_exclude_inplace(negate, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1096, in _filter_or_exclude_inplace
    self._query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1502, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1532, in _add_q
    child_clause, needed_inner = self.build_filter(
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1377, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1187, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/titsnium/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1677, in names_to_path
    raise FieldError(

Exception Type: FieldError at /answer/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'i' into field. Choices are: add_time, answer, detail, id, num_vote_down, num_vote_up, slug, tags, title, user, user_id, vote_score, votes
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic import DetailView, CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.db.models import Count
from requests import request
from .forms import QuestionForm, AnswerForm
from django.contrib.messages.views import SuccessMessageMixin
from django.urls import reverse, reverse_lazy
from . import models
from .models import Question, Answer, Comment

from vote.models import UP, DOWN
from .utilities import cast_vote, save_text_help

class QuestionsView(ListView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/questions.html'
    context_object_name = "quests"
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(QuestionsView, self).get_queryset()

        search = self.request.GET.get('q')
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(title__icontains=search)

        qs = qs.order_by("-id")
        qs = qs.annotate(count_of_answers=Count('answer'))
        return qs

class QuestionDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'forum/detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'quest'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['tags'] = self.object.tags.split(',')
        answers = Answer.objects.filter(question=self.object).order_by('-vote_score')    
        comments = []
        for answer in answers:
            comments.append(Comment.objects.filter(answer=answer))
        context['answers_comments'] = zip(answers, comments)
        
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(QuestionDetailView, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(count_of_answers=Count('answer'))

        return qs
    

class AskForm(SuccessMessageMixin , CreateView):
    template_name = 'forum/ask-question.html'
    model = Question
    form_class = QuestionForm
    success_message = 'Success!'
    
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(AskForm, self).form_valid(form)
    
class AnswerForm(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'forum/answer-question.html'
    model = Answer
    form_class = AnswerForm
    success_message = 'Success!'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.question = Question.objects.get('id')
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save()
        return super(AskForm, self).form_valid(form)

class WriteCommentAnswerView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        text=request.POST['text']
        id=request.POST['id']
        text_type = request.POST['type']
        user=request.user

        if text_type == "comment":
            return render(request, 'forum/includes/single_comment.html', {'comment': save_text_help(text, id, text_type, user)})
        else:
            return render(request, 'forum/includes/single_answer.html', {'answer': save_text_help(text, id, text_type, user)})

class SaveVoteView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def post(self, request):
        id = request.POST['id']
        user_id = request.user.id
        vote_to = request.POST['vote_to']
        vote_type = request.POST['vote_type']

        return JsonResponse({'bool': cast_vote(vote_type, vote_to, user_id, id)})
```

models.py:

```
from time import time
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from vote.models import VoteModel
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify
from users.models import CustomUser

# This is the question model
class Question(VoteModel, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    detail = models.TextField()
    tags = models.TextField(default='')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/questions/"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


# This is the answer model

class Answer(VoteModel, models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    detail = models.TextField()
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail


class Comment(models.Model):
    answer = models.ForeignKey(Answer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_user')
    comment = models.TextField(default='')
    add_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Comment on \"{self.answer}\" by {self.user}"
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('questions/', views.QuestionsView.as_view(), name='questions'),
    path('ask/', views.AskForm.as_view(), name='ask'),
    path('answer/', views.AnswerForm.as_view(), name='answer'),
    path('detail/<pk>', views.QuestionDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('save-text', views.WriteCommentAnswerView.as_view(), name='save-text'),
    path('save-vote', views.SaveVoteView.as_view(), name='save-vote'),
]
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Answer, Question

class QuestionForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['title', 'detail', 'tags']
        exclude = ('user', 'add_time')
        
class AnswerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        fields = ['detail']
        exclude = ('user', 'add_time')
```

Comment: Share your `Form`s.

Comment: hi, I edited it

Comment: `form.question = Question.objects.get('id')` makes no sense, you probably want to use `form.instance.question_id = self.kwargs['pk']`.

Comment: hey, I did that and now I get

KeyError at /answer/
'pk'

instead

Comment: The URL where you add a answer for a question should have a `<int:pk>` parameter with the primary key of the question to link the answer to.